# Function inside the card view Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

In the below function, `CardView` has to show the score, but its not changing according to value(if equal score is 10 if not score is 1.)

but I'm getting  only the difficult value 1

```
public void getOppositeUsers22(){
        usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yeps").hasChild(currentUId) &&dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue().toString().equals(oppositeUser2)) {
                        String profileImageUrl = "default";
                        Integer score2 =  1;


                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                            profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();
                             if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().equals(innduusry)) {
                                 score2 = 10;


                            }
                        }

                        score = String.valueOf(score2);


                        cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),score, profileImageUrl);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Check which of your if conditions is failing.

Comment: This one  is failing--  if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().equals(innduusry)) {
                                 score2 = 10;


                            }

Comment: print the values of `dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue()` and `innduusry` and see if they are the same

Comment: yes  value is same for industry and  innduusry but in card view only showing 1 but has to be 10 as if equals   score2 = 10;

Comment: Are you sure that `if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().equals(innduusry)` condition check is failing? then that means `dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue()` is not equal to `innduusry`

Comment: yes . firebase  database have all the profiles with same   "industry" value

Comment: Dear friends thanks for the  adivced, i have put the if statement for  profileImageUrl in side the if statement of  score2. it is working . /////

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of:

```
if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().equals(innduusry)) {
        score2 = 10;
}
```

write:

```
if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().toString().equals(innduusry)) {
        score2 = 10;
}
```

And try. Hope it works.

Comment: score is the string value of score2. what difference does it make?

Comment: i will add more if statements on later , so score2 is one variable will add more in future to get total.  score will have total calculations from  integer  variable  like  score2 .  score is string variable to add in card view

Comment: Adding  score2 in to the  cards items giving an error. score already add in to the java class cards  as a String.

Comment: Okay, What is `innduusry` @IndikaDharshana

Comment: if (dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue() != null) {
                        innduusry = dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().toString();

                        oppositeUserSex2 = "post";


                        getOppositeUsers22();
                    }

Answer (score 0):

This method is calling  getOppositeUsers22()

```
public void checkUser(){
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference userDb = usersDb.child(user.getUid());
        userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue() != null){
                        innduusry = dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().toString();

                        oppositeUser2 = "post";


                        getOppositeUsers22();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: is `innduusry` a global variable?

Comment: yes it is. this is for the the user that will use the app.

Comment: yes but still score shows as 1 not 10 even value is equal

Comment: score is skipping if condition   , so do  i need to change the position of if statement  ?

Comment: Please check what is the value you are getting in `dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().toString()` and `innduusry`